# Following academic development, citation, new publications - From a pre-existing "library"

Tags: publications, literature-search, literature

"Library" in this context means the papers/books that you have in program X (Zotero, Mendeley, etc.) forming the literary core of a project or topic.

Is there an already-established method to automatically get the latest citations (from papers in your library) or new publications (from authors in your library)? I picture something like having a "Latest developments" panel in the program X showing a list of the newest items which could be of interest according to your library.

I have never seen or heard of something like this and it might well just not exist. However I can see how this could be something very valuable for researchers looking to optimize how they keep up with literature, so maybe there is an app already out there which I might have missed so far.

Comment: I think [Sparrho](https://www.sparrho.com) was, at one point, moving toward something like this but has since changed their business model.

Comment: I'm not sure that your question is properly specified, particularly concerning the word "library". You seem to be conflating "your personal reference collection" with "external database". So, you seem to be asking how you can can automatically locate new articles from an external database based on existing articles in your personal reference collection. However, your question as phrased says nothing about what kind of external database you have in mind or how the linkage is supposed to be set up. Please rewrite your question in these terms, and then it would be easier to answer.